# Safari Async pixel calls getting cancelled

Tags: javascript, redirect, safari, tracking

In my application I have a code where I need to trigger an image pixel(tracking pixel) before redirecting user a different page. It works fine on all browsers but in Safari, for some reason the tracking pixels is not getting triggered. All the other pixels like landing page pixels work fine. Only the pixel that are supposed to trigger before redirecting to a different page are getting cancelled/not triggering. Does anybody else face this issue? if yes how did you solve it?
Also I cant throw a popup/alert as this tracking pixel needs to fire behind the scene without interrupting the user flow

Comment: `I have a code` - perhaps your code is incompatible with the way safari does some things compared with other browsers - chances are, since you're navigating, the navigation cancels the tracking request - as a matter of interest, what version of Safari on what device

Comment: This is the purpose of the [`ping` attribute on the anchor `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#ping) and [`Navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). Generally, Safari [prevents cross-site tracking](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/prevent-cross-site-tracking-sfri40732/mac). Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as one — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: By introducing a slight delay the event is firing before i redirect the user to new page/site. This is working for now but adding this delay doesnt seem right. So wanted to see if there is a better solution for this issue. And this issue only seems to happen on Safari